# Oracle 10g : ORDER SIBLINGS inside a VIEW

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, sql-order-by, ora-00907

Is it possible to add a ORDER SIBLINGS BY fieldName inside a view?
I've got a hierarchical structure, in which I'm successfully using a query with the CONNECT BY feature.

However, when I add the ORDER SIBLINGS BY fieldName inside the view definition, Oracle gives a strange parenthesis error.

```
drop view myview;
create view myview as (
select id, level as depth, label, parentid, orderhint, 
       connect_by_root myfield1 "myfield1", connect_by_root id "toplevelparentid"
  from mytable
  connect by prior id = parentid
  start with id in (select id from mytable where parentid is null)
  order siblings by orderhint
);
```

Without the ORDER SIBLINGS BY or outside a view definition it works like a charm. Otherwise, I get:

> ORA-00907: Missing right parenthesis

Comment: Not recommended, using `ORDER BY` in a view because it's not obvious to those who use the view (but can't see the query that makes it) -- waste of resources

Comment: This is not an ordinary view, it has a special purpose. I can't give all details, but order here is crucial. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried removing your parentheses:

```
drop view myview;
create view myview as
select id, level as depth, label, parentid, orderhint, 
connect_by_root myfield1 "myfield1", connect_by_root id "toplevelparentid"
from mytable
connect by prior id = parentid
start with id in (select id from mytable where parentid is null)
order siblings by orderhint;
```

Comment: I've tried lots of things, but not this simple trick. Thanks! Anyway, Oracle's error message could be more descriptive, instead of just "missing right parenthesis", which is even not the case...